# Can I use obsolete version of SDK build tools in android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sdk

I have a phone with 4.2.2(Jellybean) version, I want to create a application on that version but that version is obsolete. Can I still build on that version on Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build apps for any of the version. SDK version for [Jellybean](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.2.html) is 17. Just setup the `minSdkVersion` in `build.gradle` as 17 (or lower if you wish to use it with even earlier versions of android).

You'll also get this option to choose the minimum sdk version from the new project wizard itself while creating one.

In short, yes you can make it. Also, You may need to download the relevant API if you want to use the emulator.

Comment: I created a application with API 17 minSdkVersion but when I choose gradle 17, It says "The SDK Build Tools revision is too low for project"

Comment: Yes, because the latest is `24.0.1`. What you are seeing might be a warning because it's recommended to use the latest build-tool version. As the official docs says. `Build Tools is a component of the Android SDK required for building Android application code` If you want the app to be running on a 4.2.2 device then you don't need to use the obsolete build-tool version but the `minSdkVersion` attribute. This attribute shows the minimum Android OS version which is required for your app to run. For a nice insight to all these, go through Ian's article (link in his article, below).

Answer (score 1):

Per [this blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd), you should **always** compile with the latest SDK (and the same applies to build tools, gradle version, etc). What you compile with is independent from the minimum and target SDK version you use.